# Trying to generate a listfile for ffmpeg concatenation via drag and drop onto a batch file

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, batch-file, concatenation

Yeah so pretty simple question really, theres only 3 steps to the process:

**1.** Get alphanumeric listing by dragging and dropping files.

**2.** Edit the file list to match the following syntax/layout:

```
file 'filename1.mkv'
file 'filename2.mkv'
file 'filename3.mkv'
```

**3.** Use the listfile to concatenate the files.

The thing I can't figure out is how to generate a list of the files that are drag and dropped onto the batch file.

I'm googling it but perhaps my search terms use too many common words, either way I haven't found anything useful yet. And sorting the list alphanumerically might also be difficult, I'll probably need to use a third-party tool unless someone has a better idea.

EDIT: Someone posted this answer but removed their comment. It's a good solution. This code uses absolute paths so the dropped files could come from anywhere. The script outputs to where the batch file is located. Spaces are okay to use in the path and file names.

```
@echo off setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo. > "%~dp0Concat1.txt"
for %%A in (%*) do ( echo file '%%~A'>> "%~dp0Concat1.txt" )
sort < "%~dp0Concat1.txt" > "%~dp0Concat2.txt"
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "%~dp0Concat2.txt" -c copy "%~dp0Output.mkv"
del /Q "%~dp0Concat1.txt" "%~dp0Concat2.txt"
pause
```

Actually, it doesn't alphabetize properly, but I think someone else is working on that. Seems like more of a later issue, considering the problems I'm having. I noticed that many DVD files don't combine properly due to timestamp-related errors. I found a way to correct these errors, but I would need to first -c copy them to another file and concatenate those new files instead. My thinking is that if I can somehow omit the path from the created listfile and instead add something like %~dp0Output/ before the file name, indicating a new output folder which could be made with mkdir in the bat files directory. The new files to be concatenated and the final file could go there in the Output folder, and if the files had the same names and the full path were omitted then the listfile would still work, but would point to the new files, not the old.

Okay, first part of the code is ready:

```
@echo off setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo. > "%~dp0Concat1.txt"
for %%A in (%*) do ( echo file '%%~nxA'>> "%~dp0Concat1.txt" )
```

UPDATE: This new code is nearly complete, I just have to perform an alphanumeric sort on Concat2.txt and tell the script to replace more extension types. It should be able to concat video and/or audio and output it to Output.mkv without re-encoding. Thanks guys, you all provided valuable pieces to the puzzle. My next post will hopefully answer the question with a finished script.

Note: I found the vbscript part here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

```
mkdir "%~dp0Temp"

Echo Const ForReading = 1 > "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
Echo Const ForWriting = 2 >> "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
Echo strFileName = Wscript.Arguments(0) >> "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
Echo strOldText = Wscript.Arguments(1) >> "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
Echo strNewText = Wscript.Arguments(2) >> "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
Echo Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") >> "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
Echo Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading) >> "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
Echo strText = objFile.ReadAll >> "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
Echo objFile.Close >> "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
Echo strNewText = Replace(strText, strOldText, strNewText) >> "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
Echo Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting) >> "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
Echo objFile.Write strNewText  'WriteLine adds extra CR/LF >> "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
Echo objFile.Close >> "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs"

@echo off setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo. > "%~dp0Temp\Concat1.txt"
for %%i in (%*) do if not exist "%~dp0Temp\%%~ni.mkv" (
   ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -y -i "%%~i" -c copy -reset_timestamps 1 -video_track_timescale 90000 "%~dp0Temp\%%~ni.mkv"
)
for %%A in (%*) do ( echo file '%~dp0Temp\%%~nxA'>> "%~dp0Temp\Concat1.txt" )
sort < "%~dp0Temp\Concat1.txt" > "%~dp0Temp\Concat2.txt"

cscript "%~dp0Temp\Replace.vbs" "%~dp0Temp\Concat2.txt" ".VOB'" ".mkv'"

ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -f concat -safe 0 -i "%~dp0Temp\Concat2.txt" -c copy -reset_timestamps 1 -video_track_timescale 90000 "%~dp0Output.mkv"
del /Q "%~dp0Temp"
pause
```

Comment: Yes I understand, and I do apologize. I was forced to change tact due to some of the files I was trying to combine having timestamp issues. I had to instead re-create every file using -c copy in ffmpeg in order to fix the timestamps, and then ultimately it was those files I combined. Know at least that I already figured most everything out, and will be posting my new code shortly. First I just need to figure out how to alphanumerically sort a text file properly, that's the final step, and an important one since the listfile determines the order of file concatenation.

Comment: Regarding ordering your files alphanumerically, this was the focus and content in the first edition in the answer given. So when you mention this, it makes me understand that you didn't take advantage of the time/attention spent to help you.

Comment: By asking questions about how to do this, but then in this way, and again in this other way, to return to the primary form, this does not meet the platform's guidelines, and makes it useless and negatively harmful to the actions of those who follow these changes that Finally they become endless.

Comment: Yeah alright I'll try to keep that in mind in the future. If you read the edits I just made you may see this has not all been for nothing though, I'm working on the last touches of a rather efficient concat script

Comment: I suppose I can edit the question, cut out some of the fluff

Comment: **[When using some code, at least cite its source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820019/how-to-replace-text-without-replacing-replaced-text)**

Comment: I did, I mentioned that bit of code was posted by another user who deleted his comment. Unfortunately, I can't remember his username though.

Comment: I'm not referring to that, but to vbs in its edition (changed again) that incorporated this code from **[another author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820019/how-to-replace-text-without-replacing-replaced-text)**

Comment: Ah, yeah that's true. I could edit that in, I'll have to dig up the link though. Still, I'm not sure I like the way you pointed that out. Kinda rude. Here in Canada we put much stock in proper manners, cool?

Answer (score 0):

The apostrophe's are not required if there are no spaces in file names (I don't recommend names with spaces, when concatenating, if running Windows). The file list will also match the order the files appear in their directory.

You can combine both codes as below, or seperate into two individual scripts.

```
(for %%i in (*.mkv) do @echo file %%i) > List.txt

ffmpeg -f concat -i List.txt -c copy output.mkv
```

You can add `del List.txt` at the end to discard the created list file if required.

The above will work if run from the same directory as your files to be concatenated.

Comment: It looks like this code will concat every mkv file in a given folder from the command line, correct? While useful, this wasn't quite what I'm looking for. I'm trying to create a batch file that will concat via drag and drop, it will concat the files being drag/dropped but not necessarily every file of the same format from the source directory. Also, since the source file in many cases will be .vob files from the disk drive I can't copy the batch file to where the files are located either, but sometimes it won't be sourced from disk so I can't rely on that either.